# Domain/range of composition function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = sin x.
\\g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, g(x) = e^x.$$
Need domain/range of compositions.

That's what I got, but I'm not 100%:
$$f \circ g = sin(e^x)$$
Domain $\mathbb{R}$, range $[-1,1]$

$$g \circ f = e^{sinx}$$
Domain $\mathbb{R}$, range $[\frac {1}{e}, e]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the range consists of points already mapped by a function.  Observe that $e^x: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$ and $\sin(x) : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow [-1,1]$.  As you said
$$f \circ g = \sin(e^x)$$

and

$$g \circ f = e^{\sin(x)}$$

The mapping $g \circ f$ shows that $\mathbb{R} \longmapsto (0,\infty) \longmapsto [-1,1]$.  The mapping $f \circ g$ shows that $\mathbb{R} \longmapsto [-1,1] \longmapsto \left[\frac{1}{e}, e \right]$.

Thus, your reasoning is right.  Nicely done. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your answers are correct.

In general, the domain of $f\circ g$ is $\{x\mid x\in \text{Domain of g and }g(x)\in\text{Domain of f }\}$.

The range of $f$ is $\{y\mid y=f(x)\text{ for some }x\in\text{Domain of f } \}$.

You can check that your answers are consistent with these definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If $e^x: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$, then surely the domain of $f \circ g = (0, \infty)$.